# Unable to acquire JDBC Connection while using the Oracle DataBase with my spring app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, oracle11g

My Oracle Database keeps on disconnecting when I am using oracle database with my application and throwing the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" **org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException**: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

I am using **Java 8** and **Oracle 11g** in my application and defined the following dependencies in my **pom.xml** file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
     <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
     <version>19.7.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- hibernate-c3p0-5.3.0.Final.jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate-core-5.3.0.Final.jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

I had also defined the c3p0 properties in my hibernate oracle properties file

**oracle_hibernate.properties**

```
hibernate.ejb.metamodel.population=disabled
hibernate.generate_statistics=false
hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys=true

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

# Hibernate properties
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none

#C3P0 properties
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=300
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=150

#DATABASE INFORMATION FOR UTILITIES:
dexcenter.db.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
dexcenter.db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
dexcenter.db.userId=dex1
dexcenter.db.password=sanket
```

Any suggestions regarding this will be helpful.

Note - There is no issue in my code as it is working fine with My SQL and Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Where is the conneciton URL, username, db..etc properties

Comment: Thank you @zatef for response but there is no issue with the given things as my application is connecting with database but keeps on disconnecting in between. Please refer to my edit

Comment: Show houw you use HIbernate in your spring application, the spring configuration (not only the properties) and please add the **full** stacktrace instead of a snippet.